# jQuery animate queue: false not working to make animations simultaneous

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-animate

I've used the jQuery `queue` modifier to make animations happen simultaneously before, but for some reason I can't get it working this time.

The URL of the page in question is http://fretfast.com - when you click "notifications" at the top left, you'll see that first the bar expands sideways and then the "notifications" bar expands to fit it, and the same thing happens with the height animation.

Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
n.animate({width: em2px(35)+'px'}, {queue: false, duration: speeds['fast']/1.5});
nc.animate({width: em2px(35)+'px'}, {queue: false, duration: speeds['fast']/1.5});
```

Where `n` is the variable for the "notifications" title bar and `nc` is the variable for the notification container that expands first. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Code seems right. Have you tried running it with something simple like `n.animate({width:400},{queue:false, duration:200});` just to make sure it's not the width or duration that's breaking it.

Comment: I just tried that and it does the same thing. Thanks for the debug suggestion, though.

Comment: If you slow it way down, it seems that both animations are happening simultaneously, but with different easing patterns.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be happening because I didn't specify an easing pattern for either. How would I specify one so that I can make them the same? Sorry, I'm a bit new to jQuery.

Comment: Just changed it so they all use the same easing pattern and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have Transition properties in your CSS, on the selector you are trying to animate. 
Took me forever to figure this out, but apparently, CSS Transitions force the animation to either lag, or happen after all other animations, can anyone clarify or confirm this?

Using jQuery animations and CSS animations together can be tricky, anyone have any insight into this? Tips?

Comment: Thank you, that saved my life (well, not really, but it saved a LOT of time!) :)